# jQuery selector eq:() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I made a toggle button with pure CSS/jQuery and all works perfectly. The problem comes when I duplicated it and tried to toggle it. As supposed, the toggles 'toggled' at the same time, here is my code so far:

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">    
        <div id="switch-1"><div class="light-1"></div><div class="switch"><div class="space"><div class="circle"></div></div></div><div class="light-2"></div></div><br><br>
        <div id="switch-2"><div class="light-1"></div><div class="switch"><div class="space"><div class="circle"></div></div></div><div class="light-2"></div></div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){
            $('.space').click(function(){
                if($('.circle').hasClass("detector")){
                    $('.circle').animate({ marginLeft: "2px"}, "slow", function(){$('.light-1').css("background","#8e3135"); $('.light-2').css("background","#adafb2"); $('.circle').removeClass("detector");});
                } else {
                    $('.circle').animate({ marginLeft: "47px"}, "slow", function(){$('.light-1').css("background","#adafb2"); $('.light-2').css("background","#8e3135"); $('.circle').addClass("detector");});
                }
            });

            $('.space').eq(1).click(function(){
                if($('.circle').eq(1).hasClass("detector-1")){
                    $('.circle').eq(1).animate({ marginLeft: "2px"}, "slow", function(){$('.light-1').eq(1).css("background","#8e3135"); $('.light-2').eq(1).css("background","#adafb2"); $('.circle').eq(1).removeClass("detector-1");});
                } else {
                    $('.circle').eq(1).animate({ marginLeft: "47px"}, "slow", function(){$('.light-1').eq(1).css("background","#adafb2"); $('.light-2').eq(1).css("background","#8e3135"); $('.circle').eq(1).addClass("detector-1");});
                }
            });
        });
```

Or the Jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ew0s6nqd/

This is how it works, when you click the toggle it detects if it has a class called "detector". If it doesn't, it animates the toggle and creates one. If it does, that means that the class was previously created so it animates back the toggle and removes the class.

Ok, the problem starts when I duplicate the toggle. I have now two of them which I want to activate individually. The easiest solution was using `:eq()` jQuery selector or `.eq()` jQuery function which people classified as a more 'correct' option.

So I add it to the code of the second toggle but it didn't worked. In the fiddle above you can test it by yourself. Please if someone know which is the problems, let me know, thanks!

**EDIT:** I already used `:eq()` selector but it didn't work either.

**EDIT 2:** I use a different detector class called "detector-1" to prevent it from interfering with the other one.

Comment: is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ew0s6nqd/1/) what you are looking for?

Comment: This is hard to grok, why exactly do you have two event handlers that look exactly the same for the same elements, and what's supposed to happen here ?

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar yes but when you click the first one, both move

Comment: Pass event object as a parameter to handler function. It will allow you to determine which element triggered the event and then apply switch behaviour only to clicked one.

Comment: I think what you really want is this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/ew0s6nqd/3/**

Comment: @adeneo I barely know how to make this things in jQuery but your code is more compact so will use it in case of publishing this toggle on a webpage for minimizing size, thanks!

Comment: use of ternary operators... should have thought of that for my solution... damn...  adeneo, you got the point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function () {
    //the click function for every element with the .space class
    $('.space').click(function () {
        //check on the .circle child of the clicked .space using "this"
        if ($('.circle', this).hasClass("detector")) {
            //and animate it
            $('.circle', this).animate({
                marginLeft: "2px"
            }, "slow", function () {
                // since we are in the animate callback, "this" is now the 
                // .circle of the clicked .space
                // we want the lights to change - so we have to travel the dom upwards
                // 1st .parent() brings us to .space
                // 2nd .parent() leads us to .switch
                // siblings() let us find the .light-1 element
                $(this).parent().parent().siblings('.light-1').css("background", "#8e3135");
                // same here for light-2
                $(this).parent().parent().siblings('.light-2').css("background", "#adafb2");
                $(this).removeClass("detector");
            });
        } else {
            $('.circle', this).animate({
                marginLeft: "47px"
            }, "slow", function () {
                $(this).parent().parent().siblings('.light-1').css("background", "#adafb2");
                $(this).parent().parent().siblings('.light-2').css("background", "#8e3135");
                $(this).addClass("detector");
            });
        }
    });
});
```

using the this selector, you need to define the click handler only once - and it still works for endless numbers of buttons...
["see working fiddle"](http://jsfiddle.net/ew0s6nqd/4/)

forgot to mention. i changed the css in your fiddle, since the background image didn't show up, i created a white circle via css...

Comment: It's a good solution. More elegant way is O-O(Object Oriented) code.

Comment: and could be shortened, using ternary operators from adedneos comment in the OP. yeah that's right. but fastest was, to take the OP code, remove the second click function, and use the this selector^^

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to make it thanks to @BhushanKawadkwar

I had to use the `:eq()` selector on the click function and `.eq()` function in the other ones. I don't know why, but it works, here's the working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ew0s6nqd/2/